# Как организовать работу потоков сервера клиент-серверного приложения на языке Си?

Tags: c, многопоточность, клиент-сервер, сетевое-программирование, pthread

Задача состоит в том, чтобы написать простой сетевой чат. Нет принципиальной разницы в языке, но я решил писать на Си.
Сервер должен быть способен обрабатывать несколько пользователей одновременно, а пользователи в свою очередь должны иметь возможность запрашивать список всех активных пользователей и писать им сообщения. Если пользователь выходит из сети, то соответственно отключается от сервера и вычеркивается из списка активных пользователей.

Когда я добавил функции регистрации и выдачи списка активных пользователей, столкнулся с проблемой, что обращаясь к серверу в только что созданных потоках не вызывает проблем, но если обратиться из ранее созданного потока, то сервер зависает.
 Подумал что дело в одновременном использовании памяти, хотя это было маловероятно, ведь вводил все я один с одной машины, но на всякий случай добавил мьютексы, не помогло.

Также подумал что дело может быть в засоренном буфере ввода, но функция его очистки в некоторых местах либо не делает ничего, либо делает только хуже.
 Моя последняя догадка только в том, что моя реализация просто не подходит для pthread потоков, и нужно все переписывать с использованием общей памяти и fork(), но хотелось бы этого избежать.

Вот код
Cервер:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define PORT 8080
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define MAX_CONNECTIONS 5
#define REGISTRATION '1'
#define CHECKINFO '2'
#define SENDMESSAGE '3'
#define EXIT '4'

struct Node {
    char name[30];
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node* createNode(char* name) {
    struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
      newNode->name[i] = name[i];
    }
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

void CleanStdin()
{
  char c;
  while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
}


void pushBack(struct Node** headRef, char* name) {
    struct Node* newNode = createNode(name);
    if (*headRef == NULL) {
        *headRef = newNode;
        return;
    }
    struct Node* temp = *headRef;
    while (temp->next != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = newNode;
}

void Delete(struct Node** headRef, char* name)
{
  struct Node* temp = *headRef;
  struct Node* prev = temp;
  if (strcmp(temp->name, name) == 0) 
  {
    *headRef = NULL;
    return;
  }
  while (temp != NULL) 
  {
    if (strcmp(temp->name, name) == 0) 
    {
        prev->next = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return;
    }
    prev = temp;
    temp = temp->next;
  }
}

int Find(struct Node** headRef, char* name)
{
  struct Node* temp = *headRef;
  while (temp != NULL) 
  {
    if (strcmp(temp->name, name) == 0) 
    {
        return 1;
    }
    temp = temp->next;
  }
  return 0;
}

void PrintUsers(struct Node** headRef, int sock, int usersVal)
{
  struct Node* temp = *headRef;
  for (int i = 0; i < usersVal; i++) 
  {
    send(sock, temp->name, 30, 0);
    temp = temp->next;
  }
}


  pthread_t thread_id;
  pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
  struct Node* head = NULL;
    int server_fd, new_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int opt = 1;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int usersVal = 0;

void* mainFunc()
{
  char name[30];
  // Чтение сообщения от клиента
    while(1)
    {
      //CleanStdin();
      memset(buffer, (char)0, BUFFER_SIZE);
    char operation;
    
    if ( operation == REGISTRATION)
    {
      read(new_socket, name, 30);
      int RegCode;
      if (Find(&head, name) == 1)
      {
        printf("User already registered: %s", name);
        RegCode = 1;
      }
      else
      {
        printf("User successfully registered: %s", name);
        pushBack(&head, name);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        usersVal++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        RegCode = 0;
      }
      send(new_socket, &RegCode, 4, 0);
    }
    else if (operation == CHECKINFO) 
    {
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      printf("\nUserval = %d\n", usersVal);
      send(new_socket, &usersVal, 4, 0);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
      //PrintUsers(&head, new_socket, usersVal);
    }
    else if (operation == EXIT)
    {
      close(new_socket);
      printf("\nExited!\n");
      //Delete(&head, name);
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      usersVal--;
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
      CleanStdin();
      break;
    }
    read(new_socket, &operation, 1);
  }
  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  
    // Создание сокета
    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0) {
        perror("socket failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
      
    // Присваивание опции сокету (можно повторно использовать адрес)
    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt))) {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT );
      
    // Привязка сокета к адресу и порту
    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address))<0) {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

// Ожидание входящих соединений
    if (listen(server_fd, MAX_CONNECTIONS) < 0) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // Принятие входящего соединения
    while(1)
    {
    if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0) 
    {
        perror("accept");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    printf("\nConnected!\n");
    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, mainFunc, NULL);
  }
    return 0;

}
```

Клиент:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SERVER_ADDRESS "127.0.0.1"
#define SERVER_PORT 8080
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define REGISTRATION '1'
#define CHECKINFO '2'
#define SENDMESSAGE '3'
#define EXIT '4'

int Socket(int domain, int type, int protocol)
{
  int sock = socket(domain, type, protocol);
  if (sock < 0) {
        perror("Failed to create socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return sock;
}

void Inet_pton(int af, const char *src, void *dst)
{
  if (inet_pton(af, src, dst) <= 0) {
        perror("Invalid server address");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
}

void Connect(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen)
{
  if (connect(sockfd, addr, addrlen) < 0) {
        perror("Failed to connect to server");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void Send(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags)
{
  if (send(sockfd, buf, len, flags) < 0) 
    {
      perror("Failed to send message to server");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void Recv(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags)
{
  if (recv(sockfd, buf, len, flags) < 0) {
        perror("Failed to receive message from server");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

// Создание сокета и подключение к серверу
int Conn()
{
  int sock = Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
    Inet_pton(AF_INET, SERVER_ADDRESS, &server_address.sin_addr);
    Connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));
    
    return sock;
}

void CleanStdin()
{
  char c;
  while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
}

int main() {
  char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char symb, operation;
    int sock = Conn();
    // Первоначальная регистрация
    operation = REGISTRATION;
  Send(sock, &operation, 1, 0);
  printf("\nEnter Name: ");
  fgets(buffer, 30, stdin);
  Send(sock, buffer, 30, 0);
  int RegCode;
  Recv(sock, &RegCode, 4, 0);
  if (RegCode == 1)
  {
    printf("You was registered before");
  }
  else if (RegCode == 0)
  {
    printf("You were successfully registered");
  }
    while(1)
    {
    CleanStdin();
    memset(buffer, (char)0, BUFFER_SIZE);
    printf("\n1. Get users info");
    printf("\n3. Exit\n");
    symb = getchar();
    switch (symb)
    {
    // Регистрация пользователя
      case '1':
      {
        operation = CHECKINFO;
        Send(sock, &operation, 1, 0);
        int usersVal;
        Recv(sock, &usersVal, 4, 0);
        printf("\nAmount of users = %d\n", usersVal);
        /*for(int i = 0; i < usersVal; i++)
        {
          char name[30];
          Recv(sock, name, 30, 0);
          printf("\nUser: %s\n", name);
        }*/
        break;
      }
      case '3':
      {
        operation = EXIT;
        printf("Exiting...\n");
        Send(sock, &operation, 1, 0);
        exit(0);
      }
      
    }
  }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Не судите строго, сам знаю как все это выглядит, писал весь день без остановки, колхозил как мог, лишь бы только закончить.

Я комментировал строки, которые как мне казалось могут содержать ошибку, но разницы не было. Ошибка возникает если сделать по порядку следующее:

1. Запустить сервер
2. Запустить приложение клиента в другом окне терминала (работаю в Ubuntu)
3. Ввести имя
4. Запустить новое приложение клиента в третьем окне терминала не закрывая старого
5. Ввести имя и выйти
6. Перейти ко второму окну и попытаться получить список активных пользователей (сейчас там заглушка просто показывающая количество активных пользователей)

Есть ли возможность это исправить, или переделать уже имеющееся чтобы работало? Буду благодарен за любые советы. Ниже приведу более подробное описание задачи.

Необходимо реализовать – «ЧАТ».

Необходимо реализовать с использованием сетевых сокетов две программы: Клиент и Сервер. Сервер должен быть один. Клиентов может быть много.

Сервер.

После запуска работает в бесконечном цикле слушая закрепленный за ним сокет, пока не поступит команда на его завершения.

К серверу через сокет, могут поступать следующие виды запросов от клиента:

1. Запрос на регистрацию (сервер должен вести список зарегистрированных клиентов). При поступлении данного запроса проверяется данный список, если клиент там не зарегистрирован, то происходит его регистрация. Клиенту отправляется ответ с подтверждением регистрации или сообщением о том, что он уже зарегистрирован.
2. Запрос на получение списка зарегистрированных клиентов. В ответ сервер отправляет Имена клиентов, зарегистрированных в данный момент.
3. Запрос на передачу сообщения клиенту. (в запросе указывается имя клиента получателя и текст сообщения). Если клиент получатель не зарегистрирован в чате, то отправителю сообщения отправляется об этом информация, иначе сообщение пересылается клиенту получателю.
4. Запрос на отключение от чата. В этом случае клиент удаляется из чата.

Клиент.

После запуска запрашивает параметры сервера (адрес и порт), а также имя клиента и пытается подключиться к серверу – отправляет запрос на регистрацию. Если подключение невозможно (не получен ответ), то завершает свою работу.

Иначе либо ждет команду от пользователя, либо сообщение от сервера.

При поступлении сообщения, выводит имя отправителя и сам текст сообщения.

Пользователь может ввести следующие команды:

Получить список зарегистрированных в чате. В этом случае клиент запрашивает этот список на сервере и выводит его на экране.

Отправить сообщение. Указывается имя клиента получателя и текст сообщения.

Команда на завершение работы. Отправляется соответствующий запрос на сервер и программа завершает свою работу.

При выполнении лабораторной работы обязательно необходимо для взаимодействия использовать сокеты операционной системы.

Comment: Сокеты в плане повисания капризны (pipe то же самое), в плане - при попытке считать больше байт чем лежит в сокете может произойти повисание. Что бы избежать этого.... один из простых советов - сделайте так, что бы размер любого пакета был **одинаковый** в байтах (а недостающие байты дополняйте пробелом или нулём), Т.е. что бы размер в recv и send был всегда одинаковый - так само проще избежать непоняток. У вас местами размер пакета 32 байта местами 4 байта... может произойти так что где-то на чтении программа застряла... найти это будет сложно, надо очень внимательно смотреть.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, буду пытаться дальше.

Comment: А разве read для сокета работает? Ни разу не пробовал. По-моему recv, если делать пакеты, то для read обвертку такую же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю 99%, что виснет сокет на попытке считать что-то, чего в нем нету, что бы это вылечить -
сделайте размер пакета одинаковым. Переписать на pipe не поможет, особенность виснуть - прикол локального сокета/pipe, сетевой будет выбивать по timeout. Я с этим не раз сталкивался.

У вас вижу число 30, например выберем размер пакета 30, тогда... я бы поправил

```
void Send(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags)
{
  char packet[30] = {0,}; // Резервируем буфер
  if (len > 30) return; // страховка, пересывемый размер не должен быть больше чем условились, можно использовать assert, можно бить на несколько пакетов, так делаем что бы было проще
  memcpy(packet, buf, len); // len не должна быть больше длинны пакета! 
  if (send(sockfd, packet, 30, flags) < 0) 
  {
    perror("Failed to send message to server");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
}

 void Recv(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags)
 {
    char packet[30] = {0,}; // Резервируем буфер
    if (len > 30) return; // страховка, пересывемый размер не должен быть больше чем условились, можно использовать assert, можно бить на несколько пакетов, так делаем что бы было проще

  if (recv(sockfd, packet, 30, flags) < 0) { // Читаем пакет.
      perror("Failed to receive message from server");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 
 memcpy(buf, packet, len); // Достаём из пакета нужное к-во байт
 }
```

`= {0,};` нужен что бы хвост пакета содержал нули, а не мусор, так пррще отлаживать, в рилизе можно убрать.

Пакеты длинее 30 будут отбрасываться return и не пересылаться,
нужно или дописывать дробление пакета на мелкие, либо увеличить размер пакета, либо после того как ошибка будет найдена - вернуть код этой функции как было, если удастся понять где ошибка в "протоколе верхнего уровня", т.е. в правилах обмена REGISTRATION, EXIT и т п.

На сервере получение пакета можно логировать в консоль, выводить send/recv и первый байт например:  `printf("recv %c" , packet[0])` или `printf("recv %i" , packet[0])`  или `printf("recv %x" , packet[0])`  если пакеты ASCII то первое, если двоичные или смешанные то лучше второе.... а дальше думаю заработает и будет видно где затык.

---

Ещё ошибки

1. read для сокета... если работает то тоже обвернуть как Recv, если не работает - заменить на recv. По документации надо recv кажись использовать.
2. Второй клиент будет перетирать new_socket и... первый клиент отвалится и т д. Нужно...

а) самый простой вариант создаём thread, в процедуре thread присваиваем new_socket из глобальной области в стековую переменную, но в материнском thread делаем sleep 100 милисекунд, что бы thread успел её считать. Т.е. `void* mainFunc(){int new_socket = ::new_socket;` либо `int new_socket2 = new_socket;` и перебивать имя сокета. Не очень надёжно... можно прилепить semaphore/event и т п для нажёжности, либо увеличивать время sleep.

б) лучший вариант, правим `void* mainFunc()` на  `void* mainFunc(void * arg)` из arg читаем сокет socket  `void* mainFunc(void * arg) { int new_socket = (int)arg; }`  если не ест то `int new_socket = reinterpret_cast<int>(arg)`, аргумент передаём `pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, mainFunc, /*тут*/ (void*)new_socket)` касты разобраться. Можно погуглить примеры серверов типа "простой http сервер на си" и там это подглянуть как сделано.

https://jameshfisher.com/2017/02/28/tcp-server-pthreads/ - вот так правильно, хотя не везде соберётся.

Брать адрес глобальной переменной нельзя, т.к. она будет стёрта сделующим запросом, некоторые такую ошибку делают. malloc - тоже так себе вариант.

в) Если не получилось a и б - создаем массив, делаем счётчик. В массив материнский thread складывает new_socket обязательно с mutex и до создания thread, а новый thread обязательно с этим же mutex забирает через счётчик new_socket назад себе и сохраняет это значение обязательно в стековую переменную, её и подставлять в recv/send. Массив на хотя бы 8 элементов, при переполнении массива - ждать, если не проверять массив - приложение упадёт если много клиентов одновременно зайдут.

Comment: Действительно, дело было в использовании глобальной переменной для сокета. В каждый поток нужно было передавать свой отдельный сокет, теперь все работает корректно. Спасибо за помощь!